# Dimmer switch wiring

Tags: wiring, dimmer-switch

I'm slightly confused by the wiring of this old dimmer switch (UK based).
The black/red part of the dimmer is connected to a light that works fine
The blue part of the dimmer (with the white cable) seems to have no effect.

What I know:

- Both L1 seem to be hot wires

Questions:
I want to replace the dimmer with a new lightwave dimmer.

- I'm unsure why the white cable has been connected to the X symbol. Isn't it likely that the white cable is neutral?
- The disconnected cable was in the black/red part of the dimmer connected to the 0. It did work fine, but why is it marked as 0?

[image]

- The disconnected cable was connected to the 0 in the black/red part of the dimmer

Comment: Do yourself a diagram of the wires connecting to the old dimmer and then work out the equivalent positions on the new. If you cannot sort this out then STOP and get an electrician to do it properly. If you do it incorrectly then may just be a fuse that blows or you could burn the house down.

Comment: What you're looking at here is a 2-way switch (3-way in American terminology). None of those wires is Neutral. If your new smart dimmer needs neutral then you're out of luck.

Comment: Can you post photos looking into the *back* of the box please?